# How to determine active post category?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have a dropdown menu for categories and posts within them. Need to check if category is active - the opened post to use active class for menu category.
Posts can have new categories, they are not predefined.

Front matter is standard:

```
---
layout: post
title:  "Some post title"
date:   2016-04-06 13:41:07 +0300
category: Events
---
```

In order to show class for open post in menu, I use a common technique

```
{% if page.url == post.url %}
<li class="active"><a href="{{post.url | prepend: site.baseurl}}" class="active">{{post.title}}</a></li>
{% else %}
<li><a href="{{post.url | prepend: site.baseurl}}">{{post.title}}</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

How to apply class for a dropdown category in which open post is present?

Here's full code of categories with nested post titles for output, I currently have:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
Categories
<li class="dropdown active">
{% for category in site.categories %}
<li><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" name="{{ category | first }}">{{ category | first }}</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
{% for posts in category %}
{% for post in posts %}
{% if page.url == post.url %}
<li class="active"><a href="{{post.url | prepend: site.baseurl}}" class="active">{{post.title}}</a></li>
{% else %}
<li><a href="{{post.url | prepend: site.baseurl}}">{{post.title}}</a></li>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
</li>
{% endfor %}
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
{% for category in site.categories %}

  {% assign categoryName = category | first %}

    <li>
      <a href="#" 
         class="dropdown-toggle {% if page.category == categoryName %} active{% endif %}" 
         data-toggle="dropdown" 
         name="{{ categoryName }}">{{ categoryName }}</a>
    ...
```